# How can I trigger a non-static method upon Autocomplete textbox selection from JQuery to aspx.cs

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have got a autocomplete textbox implemented using JQuery where the user selects a particular city name.

> ```
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         $('#txtName').on('change', function () {
>             $('#selectedItem').html(this.value);
>         }).change();
>         $('#txtName').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
>             $('#selectedItem').html(ui.item.value);
>         });
>     });
> ```

The selected city name from Autocompete Textbox is being stored in label - SelectedItem. This label value has to be passed as a parameter to code-behind method (aspx.cs).In this code behind method I will connect to SQL database to fetch the details of that city and display the result in GridView.

I would like to know how can I trigger a code behind method every time user selects from the autocomplete Textbox.

Please guide me through this, I'm stuck for a week. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please support your question with code snippets what you have tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up an ajax request to be able to call codebehind (server-sided) methods from javascript/jquery (client-sided). Otherwise server and client can't communicate magically.

Then, the client side javascript, will make a request to server and return the result to your page, and you will have to elaborate it.

Try looking at [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx) and [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/DropDownList-SelectedIndexChanged-event-inside-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)